How to add Dynamic Filter in CRMA Dashboard in Community?
We have added CRMA dashboard to our community site. This dashboard displays all the data. If I pass AccountId value as hardcoded as below:
    {"datasets": {
        "order_history_account":[
          {
            "fields":["Account.Id"], 
            "filter": {
              "operator": "matches", 
              "values":["0015r00000Y8CdCAAD"]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }

Then it shows me correct result, but I want to form a Dynamic Filter where it should dynamically pass Current user's Account Id. I tried different ways but it's not working. Also the documentation is not clear.
Can someone please help me how I can pass Dynamic Filter Account Id value in it?
